# How to add form attribute in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, zurb-foundation

I know that to insert a attribute in forms in laravel we do something like below

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'comment', 'method' => 'post')) }}
```

But what i want to do is insert a attribute like this and not in commas

```
<form data-abide>
```

Because I'm using foundation as a front end framework so need to use its validation.

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: It worked beautifully but not with the submit false.

Comment: Yes, that I have add for example....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it similar way you add method :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'comment', 'method' => 'post', 'data-abide' => 'formclass', 'onSubmit' => 'return false;')) }}
```

Comment: Worked but with out submit false :)